# reading file to a list

Tags: c#, file.readalllines

i have a text file  like this

```
a1,b1,30.04.2017
c1,d1,30.05.2017
```

i want to add every line to a list, the first two columns will be string variables s1 and s2 and the third one will be converted to a variable showing a date

i am not experienced at all and usually i find my answers searching here. i can only find examples reading  lines containing the name of the variable and the value,

i think i will need to use the code below

```
 List<string> fileLines = new List<string>();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

    }
}
```

i cannot do the things inside the bracket, namely , 
parse the line , 
assign first column  to variable s1
assign second column to variable s2
convert the third to date and assign it to d1 
then add line to list

thanks in advance

Comment: am i using the term "list" wrong?  can a list have mutiple columns and rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code below i write the parsed data, and you can use them how you want:

```
List<string> fileLines = new List<string>();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line == "") continue; // refuse bare lines...
                string a = line.Split(',')[0];
                string b = line.Split(',')[1];
                DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(line.Split(',')[2], "dd.MM.yyyy", null);
                fileLines.Add(line); // if you want....
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer .     how will add the line to the list ?

Comment: the last line `fileLines.Add(line);` do this.

Comment: should i declare the list beforehand? like    var fileLines=new[] ;

Comment: There is in your question. `List<string> fileLines = new List<string>();` I did not repeat this in my answer.

Comment: sorry i missed it

Comment: @kenan . if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: last line filelines.Add(line) adds unsplitted line to list. how can i add it as three entries

Comment: You can add a string to `List<string>` by `theList.Add()`. In your case you can add `a` by `filelines.Add(a)` or add `b` by `filelines.Add(b)` or add `dt` by `filelines.Add(dt.ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

var text = File.ReadAllText(@"[FILEPATH]");

var fileLines = text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

But again, this could have been easily googled.

Just in case, if you need the complete code: Here is my version

```
private static void TestReader()
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\sample.txt");
        var fileLines = new List<SampleData>();
        foreach (var fileLine in text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            var lineData = fileLine.Split(',');

            // Make sure all the keys are present / do a separate check
            if (lineData.Length <= 2)
            {
                continue;
            }

            fileLines.Add(new SampleData
            {
                Code = Convert.ToString(lineData[0]),
                Description = Convert.ToString(lineData[1]),
                SelectedDate = lineData.Length >= 3 ? DateTime.ParseExact(lineData[2], "dd.MM.yyyy", null) : DateTime.MinValue
            });
        }
    }

    public class SampleData
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: does this split at ","

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq :

```
var query = from line in File.ReadAllLines(filename)
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
let words = line.Split(";")
select new { Item1 = words[0], Item2 = words[1], Date = DateTime.ParseExact(words[2], "dd.MM.yyyy", null) };
```